# Transform a row of the data frame into several rows if there is a cycle in the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have [a dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uz9w2mJ0eWHT6LeBUfYl3-Bq_ANK-a2t/view?usp=sharing) which I want to convert part of some lines into several lines.  In fact, the lines represent a question in the `Questions` column and answers to these questions in the columns `Answer_i`. For instance the following line:

```
    QID     Questions   QType   Answer_1    Answer_2    Answer_3    Answer_4    Answer_5    Answer_6    Answer_7    Answer_8    Answer_9    Answer_10   Answer_11   Answer_12   Answer_13   Answer_14   Answer_15
1177    The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been ...   Likert Scale    Very important consideration    Important consideration     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Discounted flights  Very important consideration    Important consideration     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Very important consideration    Important consideration     Somewhat consider Not an important considera...     Do not consider
```

I would like to obtain, for this line, the following dataframe:

```
    QID    Questions    QType    Answer_1     Answer_2    Answer_3    Answer_4 ...    
1263    1177    The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?    Likert Scale 
  Very important consideration  Important consideration Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider 
1264    1177_1  Discounted flights  Likert Scale    Very important consideration    Important consideration Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider 
1265    1177_2  Baggage policy    Likert Scale  Very important consideration    Important consideration Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider
```

Until now I tried to iterate on the answers:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    passed_items = []
    for cell in row:
        if cell in passed_items:
            print("need to create a new line")
            answers = {f"Answer{i}": passed_items[i] for i in range(0, len(passed_items))} # dyanmically allocate to place them in the right columns
            dict_replacing = {'Questions': questions, **answers} # dictionary that will replace the forle create the new lines
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_replacing)
            df = df1.combine_first(df)
            passed_items = []
        passed_items.append(str(cell))
```

But  it gives me back:

```
    Answer_2    Answer_9    Answer_0    Answer_1    Answer_10   Answer_11   Answer_12   Answer_13   Answer_14   Answer_2    Answer_3    Answer_4    Answer_5    Answer_6    Answer_7    Answer_8    QID     QType   Questions
0   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     The airline/company you fly with
1   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     The departure airport
2   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Duration of flight/route
3   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Price
4   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Baggage policy
5   NaN     NaN     Very important consideration    Important consideration     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  Do not consider     Baggage policy  Discounted flights  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Environmental impacts
1263    Important consideration Somewhat consider No...     Do not consider     NaN     Very important consideration    Baggage policy  Very important consideration    Important consideration     Somewhat consider Not an important considera...     Do not consider     NaN     Do not consider     Discounted flights  Very important consideration    Important consideration     Somewhat consider   Not an important consideration  1177.0  Likert Scale    The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been ...
```

The order of the columns is not respected and some of them are double.

## Update

I've been trying to understand Rob Raymond's answer.

I don't get:

- the for loop: `for i in range(3, len(r)-len(repeat)):` Are we iterating sobre each columns until the last one of the dataframe?
- the explode function `df.apply(lambda r: getquestions(r), axis=1).explode("Questions")`:

According to [w3ressource](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-explode.php#:%7E:text=The%20explode()%20function%20is,row%2C%20replicating%20the%20index%20values.&text=Exploded%20lists%20to%20rows%20of,be%20duplicated%20for%20these%20rows.):

> The explode() function is used to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values.

Is it this thing that transform r into the lists I was looking for?

- how it creates a new datagram. I get it is related to the preceding answer.

Here is the code, with my comments:

```
import collections
df = pd.DataFrame({"QID":[1177],"Questions":["The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?"],"QType":["Likert Scale"],"Answer0":["Very important consideration"],"Answer1":["Important consideration"],"Answer2":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer3":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer4":["Do not consider"],"Answer5":["Discounted flights"],"Answer6":["Very important consideration"],"Answer7":["Important consideration"],"Answer8":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer9":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer10":["Do not consider"],"Answer11":["Baggage policy"],"Answer12":["Very important consideration"],"Answer13":["Important consideration"],"Answer14":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer15":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer16":["Do not consider"],"Answer17":["Price of flights"],"Answer18":["Very important consideration"],"Answer19":["Important consideration"],"Answer20":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer21":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer22":["Do not consider"],"Answer23":["Insurance"],"Answer24":["Very important consideration"],"Answer25":["Important consideration"],"Answer26":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer27":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer28":["Do not consider"],"Answer29":["Airport services"],"Answer30":["Very important consideration"],"Answer31":["Important consideration"],"Answer32":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer33":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer34":["Do not consider"],"Answer35":["Environmental impact"],"Answer36":["Very important consideration"],"Answer37":["Important consideration"],"Answer38":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer39":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer40":["Do not consider"],"Answer41":["In-flight service"],"Answer42":["Very important consideration"],"Answer43":["Important consideration"],"Answer44":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer45":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer46":["Do not consider"],"Answer47":["Customer support"],"Answer48":["Very important consideration"],"Answer49":["Important consideration"],"Answer50":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer51":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer52":["Do not consider"],"Answer53":["Overcrowding on aircraft/airports"],"Answer54":["Very important consideration"],"Answer55":["Important consideration"],"Answer56":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer57":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer58":["Do not consider"],"Answer59":["Airport safety after COVID-19"],"Answer60":["Very important consideration"],"Answer61":["Important consideration"],"Answer62":["Somewhat consider"],"Answer63":["Not an important consideration"],"Answer64":["Do not consider"],"Answer65":["Refund policy"]})
def getquestions(r):
    # counter
    repeat = list({k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(r[3:].values).items() if v>1}) # get all the questions
    questions = []
    firstfound = 0
    # 
    for i in range(3, len(r)-len(repeat)): # I don't get this one
        if r[i:i+len(repeat)].tolist()==repeat: # I think we are trying to get the subset that are repeat
            if r[i+len(repeat):i+len(repeat)+1].values[0] is not None: # here we get the question
                questions.append(r[i+len(repeat):i+len(repeat)+1].values[0]) # we store it
            if firstfound==0: firstfound = i+len(repeat) # so when it's not 0, we do not update? Why? Why is this thing for?
    if len(questions) > 0: #weird cases ?
        # somethong odd, sometimes it's a list other times a str
        newq = r[1] + questions if isinstance(r[1], list) else [r[1]] + questions
        r[1] = newq
        # reset all the questions that have been used by list
        for i in range(firstfound, len(r)):
            if isinstance(r[i], str): r[i] = None
    return r
def fixqid(c):
    return [id if i==0 or c[i-1]!=id else f"{id}_{i}" for i, id in enumerate(c)]

df = df.apply(lambda r: getquestions(r), axis=1).explode("Questions").reset_index().drop("index", 1) # what does explode stands for?
df["QID"] = fixqid(df["QID"].values)   
df
```

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.csv'). This works fine for me

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma it probably reads the dataframe, but maybe don't convert part of some lines into several lines like I showed above

Comment: It is importing correctly for me, maybe you have some problem in your computer, not in your code

Comment: How did you read the dataframe? show the code

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma I didn't, I'm trying with the excerpt I gave above, index 1263

Comment: I am asking about how did you get your 'df', show that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sophisticated transformation

1. at the core build *Questions* as a list of embedded questions then `explode()`
2. have used `collections.Counter()` to key unique values in *Answer#* columns then eliminated ones that only occur once
3. with this *list* move it across the columns to find positions it matches.  Take next column as an embedded question,  add it to list
4. once have embedded questions, put list back into *Questions* column.  Reset all answers that are redundant
5. post process to fix up *QID* column

This actually finds 10 embedded questions in this example.  I've note included **output** as it's to wide to format sensibly

```
import collections
df = pd.DataFrame({"QID":[1177,"1177R"],"Questions":["The travel restrictions of COVID-19 have been lifted and you are looking to book a flight. To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?","How would you like to book your next holiday?"],"QType":["Likert Scale","Likert Scale"],"Answer0":["Very important consideration","Airline XYZ app"],"Answer1":["Important consideration","Airline XYZ website"],"Answer2":["Somewhat consider","Third party website"],"Answer3":["Not an important consideration","Third party app"],"Answer4":["Do not consider","Travel agent"],"Answer5":["Discounted flights","Call"],"Answer6":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer7":["Important consideration",""],"Answer8":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer9":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer10":["Do not consider",""],"Answer11":["Baggage policy",""],"Answer12":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer13":["Important consideration",""],"Answer14":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer15":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer16":["Do not consider",""],"Answer17":["Price of flights",""],"Answer18":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer19":["Important consideration",""],"Answer20":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer21":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer22":["Do not consider",""],"Answer23":["Insurance",""],"Answer24":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer25":["Important consideration",""],"Answer26":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer27":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer28":["Do not consider",""],"Answer29":["Airport services",""],"Answer30":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer31":["Important consideration",""],"Answer32":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer33":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer34":["Do not consider",""],"Answer35":["Environmental impact",""],"Answer36":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer37":["Important consideration",""],"Answer38":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer39":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer40":["Do not consider",""],"Answer41":["In-flight service",""],"Answer42":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer43":["Important consideration",""],"Answer44":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer45":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer46":["Do not consider",""],"Answer47":["Customer support",""],"Answer48":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer49":["Important consideration",""],"Answer50":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer51":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer52":["Do not consider",""],"Answer53":["Overcrowding on aircraft/airports",""],"Answer54":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer55":["Important consideration",""],"Answer56":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer57":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer58":["Do not consider",""],"Answer59":["Airport safety after COVID-19",""],"Answer60":["Very important consideration",""],"Answer61":["Important consideration",""],"Answer62":["Somewhat consider",""],"Answer63":["Not an important consideration",""],"Answer64":["Do not consider",""],"Answer65":["Refund policy",""]})
def getquestions(r):
    repeat = list({k:v for k,v in collections.Counter(r[3:].values).items() if v>1 and isinstance(k, str)})
    if len(repeat)<3: return r
    questions = []
    firstfound = 0
    for i in range(3, len(r)-len(repeat)):
        if r[i:i+len(repeat)].tolist()==repeat:
            if r[i+len(repeat):i+len(repeat)+1].values[0] is not None:
                questions.append(r[i+len(repeat):i+len(repeat)+1].values[0])
            if firstfound==0: firstfound = i+len(repeat)
    if len(questions) > 0:
        # somethong odd, sometimes it's a list other times a str
        newq = r[1] + questions if isinstance(r[1], list) else [r[1]] + questions
        r[1] = newq
        # reset all the questions that have been used by list
        for i in range(firstfound, len(r)):
            if isinstance(r[i], str): r[i] = np.nan
    return r
def fixqid(c):
    qid = []
    sub = 0
    for i, id in enumerate(c):
        if i==0 or c[i-1]!=id:
            sub=0
            qid.append(id)
        else:
            sub +=1
            qid.append(f"{id}_{sub}")
    return qid 

df = df.apply(lambda r: getquestions(r), axis=1).explode("Questions").reset_index().drop("index", 1)
df["QID"] = fixqid(df["QID"].values)   
df.iloc[:,:10]
```

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful :) I'm going to try to do it for all lines of the dataframe that have this issue :) Many thanks again

Comment: I've just updated the answer as I did run it over full dataframe. A few quirks to deal with NaN in *Answer#* and correct increment on QID

Comment: Many thanks for that! I've been trying to understand your answer. Would you mind if I ask a few answer? I'm really interested on how you did it to learn and do the same next time I face such an issue. I've updated a bit my question with my doubts.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Happy to - stack overflow has chat.  Never used it :)

Comment: `for i in range(3, len(r)-len(repeat)):` your answers start in column 3, so that's where 3 comes from.  `if r[i:i+len(repeat)].tolist()==repeat:` is picking a list of columns based on size of repeating group of questions found. don't want to spill over the end and get an index out of bounds error.  hence end point of range.  As noted it's a moving window where it's looking for a *list* to *list* equality to know it's found another repeating list